# King + Knight + Pawn vs. King

Tags: programming, knight-endgame

I'm new to the forum, greetings to all. As retired software developper I have some time over to learn game theory and to develop my own chess engine. Since I don't want to copy Stockfish code I'm writing all things for my own.

Currently i write code in C++/C for endgames for my evaluation function.
My question:

In a **King+Pawn v/s King** endgame there is an easy way to check if the game is
won or draw for the stronger side with a small table of 64x64x8 bytes.

Now, i devlop code for a **King+Knight+Pawn v/s King** endgame.

Is there any easy way to compute if this endgame is won or a draw for the
stronger side **without the use of endgame tablebases?**

If the weaker King can capture the Pawn before the stronger King or Knight
can defend it, the game will end as a draw.

Comment: There are also fortress positions such as knight defending pawn on seventh rank and king trapped in front of pawn.

Comment: @Lucenaposition: And stuff like Kh1 Pb4 Na6 - Kb5. Moreover, Kd6 Nd5 Pd7 - Kd8 and such. But everything else should be won. OP might check against "stalemate or fortress or pawn falls in 3 moves at most".